# My application disappears when I import ngbModule

Tags: angular, npm

Not sure why this is happening but as soon as I import my ngbModule after installing it with NPM, my application disappears and I have to remove the import statement in order for it to come back. I'm using Angular 9+ and bootstrap 4 and it compiles without any errors.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I checked the console.log and the answer was to use this statement in my command line for installation:

ng add @angular/localize

It's a new thing with Angular 9+ so previous versions of Angular may not run into this issue